# How to check version of Aersopike tools installed on a server

Tags: centos7, aerospike

How can I check the version of aerospike tools installed on the server? My server version is Linux CentOS 7.

Aerospike version is 3.7.1
AMC version is 3.6.11

I can get server version by running `asinfo -v version` but i'm struggling to find the version of the Tools installed. The link for the Tools is below.

http://www.aerospike.com/download/tools

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the package version use:

```
rpm -qi aerospike-tools
```

Some of the tools also have an `--version` option. These versions track the individual tools release and are independent of the package version.

```
rpm -qi aerospike-tools 
Name        : aerospike-tools
Version     : 3.9.0
...
```

For instance, asadm supports `--version` and its release notes can be found at https://github.com/aerospike/aerospike-admin/releases.

```
$ asadm --version
0.1.4
```